# Call to possibly undefined method addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3

For some reason I can't add event listeners.. I've searched the error but people say it's due to having the addEventListener outside of a function. However mine is inside the constructor!

```
package {
import flash.events.*;

public class keyClass {
    var keyArray:Array = new Array  ;

    public function keyClass() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
            keyArray[i] = false;
        }
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKyDwn);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onKyUp);
    }
    public function onKyDwn(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        keyArray[e.keyCode] = true;
    }
    public function onKyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        keyArray[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `addEventListener` is a function of the class [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6), which you must extend to use it.

So, in your case, change your class definition to:

```
    public class keyClass extends EventDispatcher {
```

Also, don't bother looking into the `IEventDispatcher` interface. For reasons unknown it has been made unimplementable. The only way to get native event functionality is by extending `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: Uhm, IEventDispatcher works just fine for me. Why is it unimplementable in your oppinion?

Comment: Then either you know a trick that I don't, or you haven't had to use the target of your custom IEventDispatcher's Event yet. According to [Robert Penner](http://flashblog.robertpenner.com/2009/09/my-critique-of-as3-events-part-2.html), the creator of AS3 Signals, it isn't possible to set an Event's target from outside. It can only be done by the EventDispatcher class itself.

Comment: Of course you can implement `IEventDispatcher`, just [proxy the calls to `EventDispatcher`](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-quick-tip-dispatching-events-without-extending-eventdispatcher/).  This is helpful if you need to extend a class which doesn't extend `EventDispatcher` *(another reason Adobe really should have just made events a full-fledged language feature...)*